# How to render byte[] to image in <img> in angular 9

Tags: html, angular

I'm not able to render my byte[] to the image. I found various solutions but till now no one is working for me in Angular 9.

Image model

```
export class Image {
    id: string
    imageName:  string
    imageData: any
    message: string
}
```

.ts file

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Service} from 'src/app/services/Service.service';

constructor(private service: Service, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

image: Image;
imgRecourse: SafeResourceUrl;

this.service.getImage(imageId).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.image = data as any;
        this.imgRecourse = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpg;base64,' + this.image.imageData);
      }
    )
```

HTML

```
<div class="picture" *ngIf="imgRecourse">
   <img id="img" src="{{imgRecourse}}">
</div>
```

and it's showing me one **warning** in every solution which is

```
core.js:6901 WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value SafeValue must use [property]=binding: data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAQ4B4ADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEC...
```

Please help me out

Thanks.

Comment: Just an observation, you are binding to imgRecourse in the html, but in your code you have this property as "imgRecourse1" . It should be red flagged as a compile time error.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @allan. I have updated the question but that was not the problem. Please could you help me in that question. Or if you know anyone please share this question link with him. Thanks 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <div class="picture" *ngIf="imgRecourse">
     <img id="img" [src]="imgRecourse">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @allan for correcting my silly mistake.

Comment: Sure, I should have spotted this earlier but I think the previous typo is what threw me off!